# What CORS policy to use for iOS and Android apps?

Tags: api, rest, cors, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I'm building an API that is meant to be used by iOS/Android apps.
The app uses JSON Web Token to authenticate users.
I ran into CORS issues when trying to talk to the API from the native app.
So I added CORS Headers for **ALL Origins** (only on urls starting with `/api/`).
It works fine now, but I'm wondering if what I did is not a potential vulnerability?

Should I allow ALL origins? If the API is going to be requested by native apps, is there a way I can know the Origin host in advance?

I'm quite confused.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7):

The user shouldn't need CORS protection if they have the token. The token is fully identical to the user logging in with their user name and password *each* and *every* time you send the token to the server. The threat model that CORS is protecting against is a malicious domain/site, other than your own site, doing an AJAX request to your server using the cookies (including session id) for *your* domain.

If a malicious domain or entity has your user's token, your user's identity is so PWN'd, that it doesn't really matter what sort of CORS protection you try to do.  The malicious domain has the equivalent of your user's username and password.  They are *completely* compromised, until you invalidate their token.

Thus, don't worry about where a request is coming from ( CORS ), when the malicious entity has completely compromised the user's account.  Just protect the token as if it were the Queen's jewels.  Send it over SSL and store it securely.  If the malicious entity gets the keys to Fort Knox, you have bigger problems than where the request is coming from.

Answer (score -2):

Don't Be afraid of let the Cors Origin : * because if you limit server access you may put your business in bad unstable situation so work hard on tokens.

But in my manner I research net and found any encryption have an decryption sometimes as a third party tool and say wow.

Finally Make my own Encryption in 20 days and each day make it harder to decrypt.

**Final Answer** : understand encryption & decryption then make your functions the way you want and everyone doesn't know.

Don't waste your time for SSL or Internation HASH Algorithms if you want Maximum Security. Afterward you can mix your encryption with International hash algorithms as you like.

Begin from easy character encoding then update and update more , one time you did it you can use in every app you make.

Hope to be helpful.

Comment: This answer reeks of terrible practice, terrible understanding of the basics and a terrible sense of how difficult it is to make systems secure. This answer should be struck altogether; don't follow any of this advice.